# Box-shadow on image using HTML vs CSS

Tags: html, css, image, box-shadow

The only working solution I've come across to put an image in a div, give it a border radius and drop a box-shadow over it is to put the URL to the image in the CSS like so:

```css
.score-image {
  border-radius: 5% 10% 15% 20%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 55px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

#score-image-1 {
  background: blue url('https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="score-image" id="score-image-1">
</div>
```

However I feel like these images are content, and in the interests of seperating content from presentation I'd like to put an image in a div in the HTML and drop the shadow over it with the CSS without using absolute positioning like is found in other solutions.  Is this possible?  It seems like the image always appears over the inset box-shadow, even when I create extreme Z-indexes to push the shadow out or bring the image back.

I've tried a number of different things but this is how I'd like to see it work:

```css
 .score-image {
  border-radius: 5% 10% 15% 20%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 55px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
 }
```

```html
 <div class="scores">
      <div class="score-image" id="score-image-1">      
        <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded" alt="Image">    
      </div>
    </div>
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this in a reasonable way, or is this a case where I just need to get over it and do it in the CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the box-shadow is part of the parent element so you have to use either a shadow element or a psuedo element.

HTML

```
<div class="img">
  <img src="https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/1918732?s=460&v=4">
</div>
```

CSS

```
img {
  display: block;
}

.img {
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.img:before {
  border-radius: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 10px #000;
  content: " ";
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oMxEMv)

Comment: Brilliant.  Thank you!

Comment: Wow, I'm just looking through it a bit trying to figure out how you came to this solution.  If I comment out any of the top, left, right and bottom lines the drop shadow disappears.  Do you know why this is?  Your solution isn't intuitive to me and I'm trying to figure out what everything does.

Comment: since the parent element is `relative` assigning the pseudo element `absolute` and setting `left`, `right`, `bottom`, `top` to 0 it creates a mask over the parent element. If you add `background-color: #000` to the pseudo element `img:before` you'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Great explanation, dysfunc.  Thinking about it like a mask makes it all the clearer -  thank you!

Comment: glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Is this the output you want to have? If so all I did was change a couple styles.

```
.score-image {
    display: inline-block; // Inline-block will make the element not 100% width.
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 55px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
    overflow: hidden; // This will make the border-radius sort of 'crop' or mask the image
}
```

https://codepen.io/bartholomewdavid/pen/ZjWrqM